# WiFi has suddenly stopped working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Firstly I am a complete noob when it comes to Linux so go easy on me, instructions with have to be super easy step by step! Thanks in advance.

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu along side Windows 10 on a Dell Precision 5520 laptop.

Everything worked fine for 24 hours but now I have no Wi-Fi, when I go to settings it says no Wi-Fi adapter detected.

I am currently using the wired Ethernet using a thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter but it is so slow it is not really usable.

How can I get the Wifi working again?

`WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-network

description: Network controller
product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 78
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
resources: irq:141 memory:edc00000-edc01fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 2
bus info: usb@4:1
logical name: enxa0cec8d6b6aa
serial: a0:ce:c8:d6:b6:aa
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.1.166 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.`

After running: sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
I get:

`[    2.233690] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.238601] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.238605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.239188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.453750] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230`

Comment: If your Ethernet connection is unbearably slow, this suggests to me that there is a problem with your network

Comment: It indeed could be a separate issue but still, my network wouldn't cause Linux not to recognise my network adapter.

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to turn off 'Fast Startup' in Windows 10. With this feature turned on Windows does not properly turn off certain things and this stops Linux from using them.

Full credit to binarysta and the full answer can be found here:
[WiFi not working Kubuntu 20.04 - Intel 8265 Network Interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593826/wifi-not-working-kubuntu-20-04-intel-8265-network-interface)